# How to create docker-compose.yml file while using jib?

Tags: angular, spring, docker-compose, dockerfile, jib

I use jib plugin to create image, while docker-compose needs Dockerfile. How can i Link already made image by jib to my docker-compose so it can build my backend in process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`gradle jibDockerBuild && docker-compose up` is a reasonable workaround. You just need to set a correct image name in the `image:` property (instead of `build:`) in `docker-compose.yml`. The `jibDockerBuild` command will be almost no-op (barring the time needed to push an image to your Docker daemon) when there is no change to your app. When you make a change, Jib will build a new image and `docker-compose` will use it. Of course, if you don't have to rebuild the image by Jib, `docker-compose up` alone will suffice, which will just use the current image in your Docker daemon cache.

Another option: pushing to and pulling from a registry (whether local or remote) with `gradle jib && docker pull <your image> && docker-compose up` may be faster if your image is large and you have decent network bandwidth. (This is because Docker Engine API has limited capability compared to Docker Registry API; Jib has to stream an entire image to a Docker daemon with `jibDockerBuild`.

Comment: So i should build image with jib first and tell docker-compose to use it right? It creates tar file as you know , so i should unzip it in a go ?

Comment: No, using `jibDockerBuild`, Jib directly pushes an image to your local Docker engine. It doesn't create a tarball. Let's say you did `-Djib.to.image=example.com/foo/image`. Then in your `docker-comose.yml`, you just say `image: example.com/foo/image` without `build: .`. Docker Compose will use the image in your local Docker engine. If `example.com/foo/image` doesn't exist in your Docker daemon, Docker Compose will try to download it from a remote registry (and fail because the server `example.com` doesn't have the image).

Comment: Where shall the docker-compose.yaml file be placed?

Comment: And how to make sure the command ./mvnw spring-boot:build-image will pick up the yaml file?

Comment: @vic Docker Compose is just a container runtime platform and is completely independent of your project, Spring Boot, or Jib. Similar to that you can maintain Kubernetes yaml files anywhere, you can have `docker-compose.yaml` anywhere you like. `spring-boot:build-image` is Spring's way to building an image and doesn't use Jib. `spring-boot:build-image` produces a very inefficient image, so you shouldn't use it when you configured Jib. Use Jib's `jib:build` or `jib:dockerBuild` instead.

Comment: @ChanseokOh Thanks for your clarification. I just started using those tools.

Comment: `docker-compose up` will work only for the first time. If you want to refresh the container with the new image you have to add `--force-recreate`.
Also, the `docker-compose` is not supported anymore and the `docker compose` should be used instead.